# What to look for in Java logs on Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to debug the following code...

```
@GET @Path("getGuestsXml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Guest getGuestsXml() {
    Guest response = new Guest("Test Guest");

    response.setId(9L);

    return response;
}
```

I keep getting an internal server error.  What should I look for in the logs on an internal server error like this?  I see numerous warnings throughout the log...

```
    .......
    org.netbeans.modules.bugzilla.exceptionreporter [1.5.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.bridge [1.10.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.modules.ant.grammar/1 [1.27.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter/1 [1.17.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter.svnkit/1 [1.2.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.libs.svnClientAdapter.javahl/1 [1.3.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.core.netigso [1.9.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.12.1 201107282000]
    org.netbeans.core.io.ui/1 [1.12.1 201107282000]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerRegistry]: No server descriptor found in J2EE/DeploymentPlugins/Tomcat55
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.ServerRegistry]: No server descriptor found in J2EE/DeploymentPlugins/J2EE
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense
    -client
    -Xss2m
    -Xms32m
    -XX:PermSize=32m
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Xmx768m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
    -splash:C:\Users\Ben\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache\splash.png
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\platform
    -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\Ben\.netbeans\7.0
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\Ben\.netbeans\7.0\var\log\heapdump.hprof
    -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy=DIRECT
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\nb;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\ergonomics;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\ide;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\java;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\xml;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\apisupport;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\webcommon;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\websvccommon;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\enterprise;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\mobility;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\profiler;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\ruby;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\python;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\php;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\visualweb;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\soa;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\identity;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\uml;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\harness;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\cnd;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\dlight;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\groovy;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\extra;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\javafx;C:\Program
    Files
    (x86)\NetBeans
    7.0.1\javacard
Compiler: HotSpot Client Compiler
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 742.4MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 32.2MB maximum 416.0MB
Garbage collector: Copy (Collections=53 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: MarkSweepCompact (Collections=4 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=8766 total loaded=8768 unloaded 2
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 4,294,967,295
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 89 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 42 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 51 binary roots took: 2381 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/web/ took: 100 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 5 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/src/java/ took: 37 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/test/ took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ContentManagement/build/generated-sources/rest/ took: 37 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/PHP/RuntimeLibraries/ took: 22 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ContentManagement/build/generated-sources/rest-test/ took: 41 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 3 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ContentManagement/web/ took: 50 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 3 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ContentManagement/test/ took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NetBeans%207.0.1/ide/jsstubs/allstubs.zip!/ took: 44 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NetBeans%207.0.1/php/phpstubs/phpruntime/ took: 50 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 10 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Users/Ben/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ContentManagement/src/java/ took: 37 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ben\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache\index\s7\html\2\1\_a3.prx (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:212)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput$Descriptor.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:76)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory.openInput(SimpleFSDirectory.java:63)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader$CoreReaders.<init>(SegmentReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:605)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter$ReaderPool.get(IndexWriter.java:622)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter$ReaderPool.get(IndexWriter.java:597)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.applyDeletes(DocumentsWriter.java:1002)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.applyDeletes(IndexWriter.java:4566)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlushInternal(IndexWriter.java:3756)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3595)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3585)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:1717)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1680)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex._store(LuceneIndex.java:365)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex.access$200(LuceneIndex.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex$1.run(LuceneIndex.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex$1.run(LuceneIndex.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.support.IndexManager$1.call(IndexManager.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:168)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.support.IndexManager.writeAccess(IndexManager.java:100)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex.store(LuceneIndex.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.DocumentIndexImpl.store(DocumentIndexImpl.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater.storeChanges(RepositoryUpdater.java:1580)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater.access$1300(RepositoryUpdater.java:158)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.scanFinished(RepositoryUpdater.java:1724)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$AbstractRootsWork.scanSource(RepositoryUpdater.java:3575)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$AbstractRootsWork.scanSources(RepositoryUpdater.java:3458)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$RootsWork.getDone(RepositoryUpdater.java:3201)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.doTheWork(RepositoryUpdater.java:2231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task._run(RepositoryUpdater.java:3988)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task.run(RepositoryUpdater.java:3928)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(TaskProcessor.java:615)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:720)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-5.3.6.0/www/benkuhl-com/dealclippings.com/ took: 416 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 12 source roots took: 835 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 24 ms]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]
Current Lucene version: 3.0.3(3.0.3 1039909 - 2010-11-28 19:08:19)
nb-lock-write.lock f: true r: true w: true
segments.gen f: true r: true w: true
segments_cz f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdt f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdx f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fnm f: true r: true w: true
_ko.frq f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tii f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tis f: true r: true w: true

Current Lucene version: 3.0.3(3.0.3 1039909 - 2010-11-28 19:08:19)
nb-lock-write.lock f: true r: true w: true
segments.gen f: true r: true w: true
segments_cz f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdt f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdx f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fnm f: true r: true w: true
_ko.frq f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tii f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tis f: true r: true w: true

Caused: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\Users\Ben\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache\index\s7\css\1\1\nb-lock-write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1066)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:888)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex$DirCache.getWriter(LuceneIndex.java:695)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex._store(LuceneIndex.java:318)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex.access$200(LuceneIndex.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex$1.run(LuceneIndex.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex$1.run(LuceneIndex.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.support.IndexManager$1.call(IndexManager.java:103)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:168)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.support.IndexManager.writeAccess(IndexManager.java:100)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.LuceneIndex.store(LuceneIndex.java:298)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.lucene.DocumentIndexImpl.store(DocumentIndexImpl.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater.storeChanges(RepositoryUpdater.java:1580)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater.access$1300(RepositoryUpdater.java:158)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.delete(RepositoryUpdater.java:1759)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.scanFiles(RepositoryUpdater.java:2180)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$FileListWork.getDone(RepositoryUpdater.java:2374)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Work.doTheWork(RepositoryUpdater.java:2231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task._run(RepositoryUpdater.java:3988)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater$Task.run(RepositoryUpdater.java:3928)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(TaskProcessor.java:615)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:720)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Current Lucene version: 3.0.3(3.0.3 1039909 - 2010-11-28 19:08:19)
nb-lock-write.lock f: true r: true w: true
segments.gen f: true r: true w: true
segments_cz f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdt f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fdx f: true r: true w: true
_ko.fnm f: true r: true w: true
_ko.frq f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tii f: true r: true w: true
_ko.tis f: true r: true w: true
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Loaders/text/x-ant+xml/Factories/ marked with the position attribute: [org-apache-tools-ant-module-loader-AntProjectDataLoader.instance], but some are: [org.apache.tools.ant.module.resources.xml-ergonomics.instance]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (nu.validator.source.LocationRecorder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO [org.netbeans.lib.profiler.infolog]: >>> Profiler agent [port=0, id=-111]: STATE_INACTIVE
INFO [glassfish]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.spi.Utils.isSecurePort(Utils.java:299)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.spi.Utils.isSecurePort(Utils.java:264)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.spi.Utils.getHttpListenerProtocol(Utils.java:229)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.common.CommandRunner.constructCommandUrl(CommandRunner.java:700)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.common.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:523)
    at org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.common.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue]: too much time in AWT thread null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've pasted the NetBeans log and not the Application server log.  If you are using GlassFish, please supply server.log which will contain the exception details.

Comment: I can't seem to find my Glassfish log location

Comment: I'm not quite sure where Glassfish has been installed on Windows. But you could try to do a search for server.log  (name of the log file).  The file should be located in GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs